# sending mail in inbox instead of spam using CDOSYS In classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

This is my code in Classic ASP and it works completely but mail sent by this code goes in Spam instead of Inbox.So what to do to send mail in inbox?

```
Dim iMsg
Dim iConf
Dim Flds
Dim smtpServer
Dim smtpServerPort
Set iMsg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
set iMsg.Configuration=iConf
With Flds
    smtpServer = "127.0.0.1"
    If Len(smtpServer) > 0 Then
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer
        smtpServerPort = 25
       .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = smtpServerPort
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup" 
        .Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Priority") = 2 '*** 0=Low,1=Normal,2=High ***'  
        .Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = 2  
        .Item("urn:schemas:httpmail:importance") = "High"  
    End If

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .update
End With
    ' Apply the settings to the message.
With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .From = sFrom
    .To = sTo
    .TextBody="This is a message."
    .Subject = sSubject

end with
iMsg.Send
set iMsg = nothing`
```

My Code Works Completely.But This mail goes into spam instead of Inbox.So,how can i send mail in Inbox?

Comment: Normally using your localhost as smtp server does not trigger spam filter (see also http://serverfault.com/questions/228604/how-do-i-get-rid-of-localhost-from-email-header) Try with another sender address, subject & body (especially this one as "This is a message." is likely to be indentified as spam)

Comment: i also try with changing server name ,address,subject etc..But that email goes in spam.